# Kafka: How to Display Offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm super new to Kafka.  I've installed kafka and zookeeper using homebrew on my mac, and I'm playing around with [the quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart).

I've been able to push messages onto Kafka using the following command and STDIN

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

and I can read things off using

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

What's not clear to me is how I use offsets.  It's my understanding that each message added to a topic will have a numerical, incremental offset value.  However, if I try to do something like this

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --offset 1
```

I get a non-zero status code and shows me no messages (other than the usual help/usage information)

I also can't get the *latest* or *earliest* keywords to work

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --offset earliest
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --offset latest
```

Both of the above also return non-zero status codes.

Do I fundamentally misunderstand offsets?  If not, is there a way to list all messages *with* their offsets?  Finally -- what's the simpliest example of the `--offset` flag for the `kafka-console-consumer`?

Comment: Hey, after looking at the source code for console consumer it appears there's no option to set offset to some value as you desire (you can do that with the actual consumer, by using the seek api call).
latest is the default (that is, if you start the console consumer without --from-beginning it will only receive "new" data). --from-beginning is the same as "earliest".

You may use the group option which allows you to reuse the same group id, guaranteeing that consecutive runs of the consumer won't receive duplicate messages.

Comment: Thank you @RoyShahaf that's super useful (especially the group info) -- random follow up question if you have a moment: "looking at the source code for console consumer" -- where did you look at the source code for this?

Comment: I'm glad I could help.
Regarding your followup question: I googled kafka-console-consumer.sh which lead me to some github with some file named kafka-console-consumer.sh which seemed to be running a ConsoleConsumer so I googled that and found something that looked relevant :)

Answer (score 5):

If you looked at the output after you gave the offset value, it would have said that you needed to specify a partition (at the top of the help section)

Topics are subdivided into partitions, and an offset of 1 could only exist on one partition out of potentially hundreds, so you must specify it

Regarding *displaying the offsets*, lookup the `GetOffsetShell` command syntax

Comment: Ah ha, thank you, super useful!  I was distracted by the "let's output all the help" behavior whenever there's an error.  I'll endeavor to RTFE in the future :)

Answer (score 5):

A nice command line tool that can display the offset with each message is `kafkacat`.

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t test -f 'Topic %t [%p] at offset %o: key %k: %s\n'
```

It will print out something like

```
Topic test [5] at offset 111: key "0171bf8102007900e33": {"Message": "1"} 
Topic test [2] at offset 123: key "070021b0f001f614c1b": {"Message": "2"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `GetOffsetShell` only [works with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688429/4470135) `PLAINTEXT`, it can be inconvenient for many.
Good news is that additional properties, including `print.offset` seems to have made their way into 2.7 based on the communication in [9099 PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/9099).
It must be possible to use `print.offset=true` now!

Comment: You can get the full list of the properties from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-431%3A+Support+of+printing+additional+ConsumerRecord+fields+in+DefaultMessageFormatter

Answer (score 2):

Partition is required when using offset

```sh
.\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --partition 0 --offset 0 --property print.key=true --property print.timestamp=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give partition value as well with offset in above command like this

kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --partition 0 --offset 1

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer, just use '--property print.offset=true':

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server XXXXXX --topic T-TEST --partition 0 --offset 0 --property print.offset=true
```