# Get the latest offsets in SSL Enabled Kafka via CMD

Tags: apache-kafka

I have being using the below CMD to get the latest offsets in from a Kafka Queue which has plain-text port open

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list server:9092 --topic sample_topic --time -1
```

But, now we only have the SSL port open, so I tried passing the SSL details as a property file

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list server:9093 --topic sample_topic --time -1 --consumer-config /path/to/file
```

Getting the below error -

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: consumer-config is not a recognized option
```

How do I pass the SSL details to this command? These are all the available arguments for kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell

```
--broker-list <String: hostname:and port,...,hostname:port>                
--max-wait-ms <Integer: ms>            
--offsets <Integer: count>             
--partitions <String: partition ids>   
--time <Long: timestamp/-1(latest)/-2             
--topic <String: topic>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately `kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell` only supports PLAINTEXT connection. This tools is not used a lot and nobody has bothered updating it.

Depending on your use case, you have a few options:

- Use the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool: Assuming you have a consumer group consuming from that topic, this tool display the log end offsets of each partitions
- Patch `kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`: It's realtively easy to add support to secured connections bby reusing logic from the other tool. If you do so, consider sending a patch to Kafka =)
- Write a tiny tool that calls [`Consumer.endOffsets()`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-)
- Use `kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments`: As a last resort this tool can also be used to find the last offset

Comment: dang, I was down a rabbit hole passing `KAFKA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore` and all that before running `kafka-run-class.sh` but the kafka server itself rejected the connection with "SSL Handshake Failed" no matter what I did. I guess the PLAINTEXT only support explains my run-class.sh output: `org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextChannelBuilder$PlaintextAuthenticator ...javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException source: jrt:/java.base`

Comment: Is there a JIRA to track this?

Comment: Yes there are a number of JIRAs for this:
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7373
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5235
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3355
and even a KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-308%3A+GetOffsetShell%3A+new+KafkaConsumer+API%2C+support+for+multiple+topics%2C+minimize+the+number+of+requests+to+server

Comment: I wanted to get offset by epoch time. What is the solution other than writing a patch?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to retrieve it on docker image `quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.29.0-kafka-3.2.0` by running:

```
./bin/kafka-get-offsets.sh --bootstrap-server "$BOOTSTRAPSERVER" --command-config kafkaConfig.properties --topic "$TOPIC" --time -1
```

where `kafkaConfig.properties` in my case contain `SASL/SSL` properties:

```
security.protocol=SSL
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
ssl.truststore.type=PEM
ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-server-ca-cert.pem
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="kafka-user" password="******";
```